# how to detect if nothing has changed in inputbox

Tags: jquery, onchange, inputbox

I have an inputbox that has default value "enter keywords". I also have two other checkboxes so users can either select checkboxes and hit search or type a keyword and search or do both. Just in case, they only select, checkboxes, I want to detect if nothing has changed in inputbox and set its value to empty. How do I do this in jquery?

```
    <input name="KeywordBox" class="BasicSearchInputBox" type="text" 
size="300" value="Enter Keywords"/>
```

Something like this???

```
if (~$("input").change(function ()) {do sth;}
```

Tried this: not working..

```
        var keywords = encodeURIComponent($(".BasicSearchInputBox").val()); 

if (keywords.indexOf("Enter Keywords") != -1)
                 {
                     url += '&k=' + checkboxValues;
                     window.location.href=url;
                 }
            if (keywords.indexOf("Enter Keywords") == -1){               
             window.location.href=url+'&k='+keywords+checkboxValues;
             }
```

Comment: Check if the value is empty or equal to "Enter Keywords". If so ignore, otherwise use the value.

Comment: Won't encodeURIComponent encode the space? As either + or %20, I forget which it is in this case.

Comment: What does encodeURIComponent do? does it perhaps encode space into %20? Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to do a watermark. Depending on your browser support requirements, you may want to take a look at the placeholder attribute.  Allows for a nice watermark without actually changing the text box's value.  (There are numerous jQuery plugins that accomplish the same thing in a cross browser manner. )

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Keywords" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `indexOf` you can do direct comparison.

```
    var keywords = encodeURIComponent($(".BasicSearchInputBox").val()); 

    if (keywords == "Enter Keywords")
    {
        window.location.href = url + '&k=' + checkboxValues;
    }
    else{               
        window.location.href = url + '&k=' + keywords + checkboxValues;
    }
```

Comment: you mean if($('.BasicSearchInputBox').val() == "Enter Keywords")

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
function defaultTxt(obj) {
    var txt=obj.val();
    obj.focus(function(){
        if(obj.val()==txt) {obj.val('');}
    }).blur(function(){
        if(!obj.val()) {obj.val(txt);}
    });
}
```

Then call assign it through a loop:

```
// Array or elements
var elems=['input'];
$(elems).each(function(){
    defaultTxt($(this));
});
```